# Stats fro GlusterFS at client end

Tags: linux, system, system-administration

How can I test the GlusterFS stats from client end ? i.e I have mounted a GFS volume on server A with mount point as /mnt/volo1. Is there any way that I can test the performance such as TPS, I/O read write speed. There is one option which does on the GFS server (gluster volume profile VOLNAME) but I wanted it at client end like we have  iostat for localdisk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [glustermg](https://github.com/gluster/gmc) , which is written in Java.